# How to terminate process in python in certain situation

Tags: python, command-line

my noob problem is: I need to run process (like dir) via cmd.exe

```
os.system("cmd.exe /c dir > output.txt")
```

but I do not want to wait for this action to finish, I need to somehow terminate it (it lasts too long, the thing I need is done at the beginning)
I hope my question is clear enough.

Please help, I've been stuck for hours

edit: the whole solution shall be placed within a python script

Comment: It's 2014. You should be using the `subprocess` module

Comment: Does your `cmd.exe` is asynchronous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should kill the task after 10 seconds

```
import time, subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen(["command"])
time.sleep(10)
task.kill()
```

If you're trying to get list of files/folders in C:\ in windows here's another way of doing it

```
import os
with open("output.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(os.listdir("C:\\")))
```

Comment: this does not work, because script will not go further, untill "command" is finished

Comment: @pawel3ala: `Popen` is non-blocking.

Comment: task = subprocess.Popen([cmd.exe /C start.bat]) gives me : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 817, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @pawel3ala, you need to five your command in form of list. check out subprocess(https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 1):

Capture the PID of your process, and then kill it as needed. For example:

```
import os
import signal

pid = os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, 'echo foo')
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```